# Python to add line when a specific line found

Tags: python

I'm having trouble writing a line to txt file when when a specific line  is found.

Here is my txt file:

```
Wed Oct  7 09:00:01

station: 01

station: 02

station: 03



Wed Oct  7 09:05:01

station: 06

station: 05
 
station: 06
```

I need the output txt file look like this:

```
Wed Oct  7 09:00:01

Time: Wed Oct  7 09:00:01

station: 01

Time: Wed Oct  7 09:00:01

station: 02

Time: Wed Oct  7 09:00:01

station: 02


Wed Oct  7 09:05:01

Time: Wed Oct  7 09:05:01

station: 04

Time: Wed Oct  7 09:05:01

station: 05

Time: Wed Oct  7 09:05:01

station: 05
```

When a date is found, it adds a new line with that date before a station. If it met a 2nd date, it adds that new date to the next station

Here is my code:

```
date1 = 'Wed Oct 7 09:00:01'
date2 = 'Wed Oct 7 09:05:01'
with open('text.txt') as f_input, open('text2.txt', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        if date1 in line:
            if line.startswith('station'):
                line = 'Time: ' + date1 + line
        if date2 in line:
            if line.startswith('station'):
                line = 'TIME: ' + date2 + line
    f_output.write(line)
```

When I run the code, the result is only "station 06".
Please let me know how to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should get the output you expect. There is an indentation error in your code and the if condition is not correct. Compare the code and you will understand.

```
import re

date = None
date_regex = "[a-z]{3}[\ ]+[a-z]{3}[\ ]+[0-9]{1,2}[\ ]+[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}"
with open('text.txt') as f_input, open('text2.txt', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        date_match = re.match(date_regex, line, re.I)
        if date_match:
            date = date_match.group()
        if date and date not in line and line.startswith('station'):
            line = 'Time: ' + date + '\n\n' + line
        f_output.write(line)
```

Comment: Hi @arulmr, the result only display 1st date, not 1st and 2nd date

Comment: @HenryNguyen I've updated the code to get the expected output. This should do it. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You are only writing one line to the file, check the indentation of the last line in your code, it is not inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the file part for obvious reasons.

```
lines = """Wed Oct  7 09:00:01
station: 01
station: 02
station: 03
Wed Oct  7 09:05:01
station: 06
station: 05 
station: 06""".split("\n")

pattern = """^(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s*\d\s*\d{2}[\:]\d{2}[\:]\d{2}"""


output = ""
last_match = ""
for line in lines:
    message = line + "\n"
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        last_match = line 
    else:
        if last_match:
            message = "Time: " + last_match + "\n" + message
    output = output + message

print(output.rstrip("\n")) # if you must remove the last EOL        
        

# output
Wed Oct  7 09:00:01
Time: Wed Oct  7 09:00:01
station: 01
Time: Wed Oct  7 09:00:01
station: 02
Time: Wed Oct  7 09:00:01
station: 03
Wed Oct  7 09:05:01
Time: Wed Oct  7 09:05:01
station: 06
Time: Wed Oct  7 09:05:01
station: 05 
Time: Wed Oct  7 09:05:01
station: 06
```